# Apple Music and gift cards

Tags: apple-music

I'm in a country where Apple Music is not available (Morocco) and I have an apple ID that I use with my all of my iDevices. Will I be able to use Apple Music using a gift card (25$ one)?

Also, what about the free, 3 month trial? Will I lose the 25$ or they will just use the gift card to verify the account?

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple, Apple music isn't available in Morocco, meaning that even is you use a gift card that you can't use it.

Other then that, you need to use a credit card to even use the 3 month free trial.

You can see the available countrys that Apple music is available in [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204956).